# PHP check CSS property

Tags: php, html

Is it possible that PHP checks a CSS property?
For example I want to assign a value if the background is red.

My variable

```
$sendTo = 'support@fantastic.com';
```

Thanks you !

Comment: for that you will need javascript, php is a server side language it doesn't interact with css

Comment: Technically it's possible, but it's a lot of work and you might be better of just doing it with javascript

Comment: if the style is inline you can check for it.. if that helps